# Paypal buttons error: 'Expected order id to be passed'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, paypal

I'm using `@paypal/checkout-server-sdk` and `react-paypal-buttons-v2`. I have almost everything set up, but I'm getting this error: `{err: "Error: Expected an order id to be passed\n}`

Here's what I have so far (PayPalButton):

```
    <PayPalButton
      createOrder={(data, actions) => {
        return createPaypalOrder(cart, currentUser.uid, cartTotal())
          .then(res => {
            return res
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('paypal createOrder error')
          })
      }}

      onApprove={(data, actions) => {
        console.log("onApprove data", data, 'actions', actions)
      }}
      // shippingPreference="NO_SHIPPING" // default is "GET_FROM_FILE"
      onSuccess={ (details, data) => {
        // Clear cart
        alert("Success: Clearing cart...")
        dispatch({type: Actions.CLEAR_CART})
        router.push('/account')
      }}
    />
```

firebase function (firebase):

```
exports.createPaypalOrder = functions.https.onCall(async (data, ctx) => {
  const apiEndpoint = "https://edit-elements.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2"
  const Prismic = require('@prismicio/client')
  const pClient = Prismic.client(apiEndpoint)
  const productIDs = Object.keys(data.products)
  const coupon = data.coupon.id ? await pClient.getByID(data.coupon.id).then(res => res).catch(err => new Error("Error verifying coupon")) : null
  const products = await pClient.getByIDs(productIDs).then(res => res.results).catch(err => new Error("Error verifying products on server"))

  // First we double-check pricing on server
  const cartTotal = () => {
    const total = Object.values(products).reduce((prev, curr) => {
      const currPrice = (curr.data.on_sale && curr.data.sale_price) ? curr.data.sale_price : curr.data.price
      return prev + currPrice
    }, 0)
    if (coupon.id) {
      return (total - ( total * (coupon.data.percent_to_discount / 100) )).toFixed(2)
    } else {
      return total.toFixed(2)
    }
  }

  const calcCoupon = (price, discount) => {
    return (price - (price * (discount / 100)).toFixed(2))
  }

  // Assemble PayPal product items array
  let itemList = []
  Object.entries(products).map(([key, prod]) => {
    itemList.push({
      name: prod.data.title[0].text,
      description: prod.data.short_description[0].text,
      sku: prod.id,
      unit_amount: {
        currency_code: 'USD',
        value: prod.data.on_sale && prod.data.sale_price ? prod.data.sale_price : prod.data.price,
        on_sale: Boolean(prod.data.on_sale),
        price_with_coupon: coupon.data.percent_to_discount ? calcCoupon((prod.data.on_sale && prod.data.sale_price ? prod.data.sale_price : prod.data.price), coupon.data.percent_to_discount).toFixed(2) : 'no coupon used'
      },
      quantity: 1,
      category: prod.data.category.uid
    })
  })
  // if (coupon.id) itemList.push({coupon_used: coupon.uid})

  // Then we create PayPal order
  const checkoutNodeSDK = require('@paypal/checkout-server-sdk')
  const env = () => {
    const clientId = functions.config().paypal_sandbox.client_id
    const clientSecret = functions.config().paypal_sandbox_secret
    return new checkoutNodeSDK.core.SandboxEnvironment(clientId, clientSecret)
  }

  const client = () => {
    return new checkoutNodeSDK.core.PayPalHttpClient(env)
  }

  // The request for PayPal
  const request = new checkoutNodeSDK.orders.OrdersCreateRequest()
  request.prefer('return=representation')
  request.requestBody({
    intent: 'CAPTURE',
    purchase_units: [{
      amount: {
        currency_code: 'USD',
        value: cartTotal()
      },
      items: itemList,
      coupon_used: coupon.uid ? coupon.uid : 'no coupon used'
    }]
  })

  let order
  try {
    order = await client().execute(request)
    return order.result.id
  } catch(err) {
    // We handle the paypal error object
    return new Error("Error with paypal: ", err)
  }
})
```

I'm just not sure what the flow is with these 2 components, and the docs are just vague enough on each to not give me enough to intuitively figure out how to route this. My guess is:

PayPal Button createOrder -(cart/uid_auth)-> custom server validation -(return orderID)-> PayPal Button onApprove/onSuccess -> SUCCESS

Comment: which line of your code produces that error?

Comment: I can't tell. I've put error logs everywhere. I think it's the response of createOrder from my server. Or rather, the final try block of my server code. It seems to come back empty, but I'm not sure where the error making it so is starting.

Comment: "Expected an order id to be passed" is triggered when no string containing an iD or promise that resolves to a string containing an ID is returned to the createOrder function call, which could happen for any number of reasons that simply need to be debugged.

Comment: One issue I see is with error handling in some places ... e.g `const products = ....` if that fails, `products` will be an error object which you then use in `Object.entries(products)` as if it were a successful result (same with `const coupon =`) ... returning a `new Error` in the `catch` means you've handled the error - so, to trace your error, you probably need to re-think your code. For a start, seeing `async`/`await` mixed with `.then`/`.catch` is not a good sign

Comment: products is handled by the state on the client-side, and the button wouldn't be an option without the products being populated.

As far as the mixture, I just don't know which to conform to. Firebase has asyn/await syntax, but the Paypal methods are all promise based. Maybe I should fix those?

Comment: In fact, the whole `const coupon` is flawed, because if there is no coupon then `if (coupon.id)` in `cartTotal` will throw - this probably isn't your issue, but I wouldn't be surprised if similar bad coding isn't responsible for the error you are getting. At guess, the error is actually something else, but it manifests as the error you are getting because you're not handling an earlier error in the correct manner

Comment: There *is* error-handling on coupon, if you look, and I've tested that. If it doesn't get a value, it will return null, and there won't be an id. The `if` you're referring to is a breakout condition, so it would fall back to the non-coupon total - no unhandled error. That's also *after* being checked client-side. I appreciate your help, but I would implore you to be reminded of the tone required on SO. Terms like 'bad code' are not welcome here. You also might want to re-review my code, please. You've seemingly missed some things. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but if there is an error on getting the coupon using `pClient.getByID` function, then, `coupon` will be an `Error` object, not null

Comment: Does an error object have an id property? Again - the coupon is checked once before this as well. It's just a sanity check. Your obsession about the error is not the issue. I've tested it.